# Dynamically change font, background colors in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, styling

We have a web application built using Angular 9. It has colors for headers, borders and some menu backgrounds stored in multiple places in css files.

The ask is to change those as per client branding. So if ClientA logs in, they should start seeing those colors as #FF0000 and if ClientB logs in, they need to see those colors as #00FF00.

Other than inline styling every html with style="color:{{clientColor}} can you help suggest the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at https://juristr.com/blog/2019/08/dynamically-load-css-angular-cli/ it might help you

Comment: @MishaMashina this requires the style (colors) to be in a css file already. In my case, I don't want to create 100s of css files for 100 clients. I would need to load the color from the DB and apply that color as a style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `:root` selector and variables in it, and for `body` tag just overwrite these root variables, working example here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujuy5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

styles.scss:

```
:root {
  --fontColor: #000;
}

.theme-dark {
  --fontColor: red;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  theme = 'theme-dark';

  toggle(): void {
    const body = document.body;

    if (body.classList.contains(this.theme)) {
      body.classList.remove(this.theme);
    } else {
      body.classList.add(this.theme);
    }

  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle color font</button>
```

app.component.scss

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
  color: var(--fontColor);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this requires the style (colors) to be in a css file already. In my case, I don't want to create 100s of css files for 100 clients. I would need to load the color from the DB and apply that color as a style

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
[style.color]="clientColor"
```